# Solving a partial differential equation (Feynman-Kac )

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I have the following PDE

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t, x)+\mu x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(t, x)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2} x^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} f(t, x) &=0 \\
f(T, x) &=\log \left(x^{2}\right)
\end{aligned}

with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ some fixed parameters.

Now, I know through Feynman-Kac that I can write
$$
f(t,X_t) = E_t [ log(X_T^2) ]
$$

where $X_t$ is geometric brownian motion ($dX_t = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t$).

Now the question is, how do I find the function $f(t,x)$?

I tried applying Itto's rule on $X_t^2$, and I get (not sure if it is correct):

$$
d(X_t^2) = (2 \mu X_t + \sigma^2 )dt + 2 \sigma X_t dB_t
$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here...

Answer (score 1):

As $X$ is a geometric Brownian motion, we know the SDE solved by $X$ has a unique solution:
\begin{equation}
X_t = X_0 e^{(\mu - \frac12\sigma^2 )t + \sigma B_t}
\end{equation}
where $\left\{B_t\right\}_{t \geq 0}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-Brownian motion.
We can also rewrite the above quantity at time $T$:
\begin{equation}
X_T = X_te^{(\mu - \frac12\sigma^2 )(T-t) + \sigma (B_T - B_t)}
\end{equation}
Using Feynam-Kac theorem (verifying we fill in the conditions), the solution of the PDE can be written as :
\begin{align}
f(t,X_t) &= \mathbb{E}_t [ \log(X_T^2) ]\\
&=2\mathbb{E}_t [ \log(X_T) ]\\
&=2\mathbb{E}_t [ \log(X_t) + (\mu - \frac12\sigma^2)(T-t) + \sigma (B_T - B_t) ]\\
&=2\log(X_t) + (2\mu - \sigma^2)(T-t) + 2\sigma \mathbb{E}_t [B_T - B_t]\\
&=2\log(X_t) + (2\mu - \sigma^2)(T-t)
\end{align}
Where in the last equation, we used that  $B_T - B_t \sim\mathcal{N}(0, T-t)$ and is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$

You can remark that the function $f$ verifies the PDE.